# Problem connecting to the PostgresSQL from Docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

Sample from class:

```
try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database='ytbstatsdb',
            host='127.0.0.1',
            user='admin',
            password='admin123',
            port='5432'
        )
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print(e)
    
cursor = conn.cursor()
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://admin:admin123@localhost:5432/ytbstatsdb')
df_videos_details.to_sql('testtable', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Docker file (docker-compose.yaml):

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin123
      POSTGRES_DB: ytbstatsdb
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

My error:

```
connection to server at "0.0.0.0", port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address (0x00002741/10049)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

The db in docker is created:
[docker-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBScl.jpg)

Hello!

I'm trying to connect to a database using docker. Accessing http://localhost:8080 is working, I can log in to Adminer and work with my database on the Adminer interface, but when I try to connect using the code from the class with psycopg2 I receive the specified error.

Do you have any clue on why I get it?

I restarted the pc to clear all the services and reset it to the essential ones, changed the port to 7432 and so on. Nothign works...

Comment: have you tried to create network using docker. eg. `docker network create <network-name>` ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is that and how should I procced. Do I need to create the network in terminal?

Comment: yes. try that command. make sure docker desktop or docker service is running.

Comment: Why do you need psycopg2.connect? Use SQLAlchemy connection like so
`engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://admin:admin123@localhost:5432/ytbstatsdb')`
You can also use **db** host name to connect from inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

you should NOT use '0.0.0.0' as source address, this address only used by sercice binding.

Comment: I modified the host to 127.0.0.1 and now it tells me that the password is not ok:
connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"

Comment: check pg_hba.conf:   `host    all   all  127.0.0.1/32    scram-sha-256`

Answer (score 0):

First check what you have set in pg_hba.conf!
If Lokalhost doesn't ask for a password, don't use it.

```
local<TAB>all<TAB><TAB>admin<TAB><TAB<TAB>trust
```

If a password is required:

```
local<TAB>all<TAB><TAB>admin<TAB><TAB<TAB>mds
```

the password must be entered in the appropriate place. Where you find it depends on the operating system.

Since it does not expect a password in the first case, it is a significant source of security-danger.